# Error signInWithPhoneNumber failed: Expected 2 arguments but got 1 signup through firebase in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

i'm new to react native i'm implementing the signup through firebase phone number otp .
    my code is:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.unsubscribe = null;
this.state = {
  user: null,
  message: '',
  codeInput: '',
  phoneNumber: '+91',
  confirmResult: null,
   };
   }
   componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
   if (user) {
    this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
    } else {
    // User has been signed out, reset the state
    this.setState({
      user: null,
      message: '',
      codeInput: '',
      phoneNumber: '+91',
      confirmResult: null,
      });
     }
    });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.unsubscribe) this.unsubscribe();
     }

    signIn = () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    this.setState({ message: 'Sending code ...' });

   firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
   .then(confirmResult => this.setState({ confirmResult, message: 'Code has been sent!' }))
   .catch(error => this.setState({ message: `Sign In With Phone Number Error: 
   ${error.message}` }));
   };

   confirmCode = () => {
   const { codeInput, confirmResult } = this.state;

   if (confirmResult && codeInput.length) {
   confirmResult.confirm(codeInput)
    .then((user) => {
      this.setState({ message: 'Code Confirmed!' });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ message: `Code Confirm Error: ${error.message}` }));
   }
  };

   signOut = () => {
  firebase.auth().signOut();
   }

   renderPhoneNumberInput() {
  const { phoneNumber } = this.state;

    return (
    <View style={{ padding: 25 }}>
    <Text>Enter phone number:</Text>
    <TextInput
      autoFocus
      style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
      onChangeText={value => this.setState({ phoneNumber: value })}
      placeholder={'Phone number ... '}
      value={phoneNumber}
    />
    <Button title="Sign In" color="green" onPress={this.signIn} />
   </View>
   );
   }

  renderMessage() {
   const { message } = this.state;

  if (!message.length) return null;

    return (
   <Text style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#000', color: '#fff' }}>{message}</Text>
    );
    }

   renderVerificationCodeInput() {
   const { codeInput } = this.state;

    return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 25, padding: 25 }}>
    <Text>Enter verification code below:</Text>
    <TextInput
      autoFocus
      style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
      onChangeText={value => this.setState({ codeInput: value })}
      placeholder={'Code ... '}
      value={codeInput}
    />
    <Button title="Confirm Code" color="#841584" onPress={this.confirmCode} />
    </View>
    );
     }

    render() {
    const { user, confirmResult } = this.state;
    return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    {!user && !confirmResult && this.renderPhoneNumberInput()}

    {this.renderMessage()}

    {!user && confirmResult && this.renderVerificationCodeInput()}

    {user && (
      <View
        style={{
          padding: 15,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#77dd77',
          flex: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Image source={{ uri: successImageUri }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, 
         marginBottom: 25 }} />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Signed In!</Text>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(user)}</Text>
        <Button title="Sign Out" color="red" onPress={this.signOut} />
       </View>
      )}
      </View>
       );
        }
        }
```

But while implementing it is saying to pass two arugument but i don't want recaptcha i just want otp. while implementing the signinwithphonenumber i'm getting this error.signInWithPhoneNumber failed: Expected 2 arguments but got 1. is it compulsion to add 2nd argument. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Are u use react-native-firebase?

Comment: @DevAs yes..........

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",

Comment: The second param for forceResend so try to add firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber,true) and then log the confirmation and let me know

Comment: i made a new project now i'm getting error RefrenceError: can't find variaable :firebase

Comment: @DevAS this is my  "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6" my package.json

Comment: the code is same

Comment: Check if you import firebase from rn-firebase

Comment: @DevAS import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

Comment: Please follow-up guide https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup

Comment: @DevAS now the error is gone but i'm not getting otp.

Comment: i have added the true which you said.

Comment: I think in debug mode you should add a test number and verify code manually in firebase console

Comment: yeah, i chacked i'm getting the phone number i'm not sure what's the problem with otp

Comment: i'm not getting otp only i even checked the firebase thr phone auth is enabled.

Comment: Try to log confirmationResult

Comment: Now i'm getting Signin Withphonenumber Error : this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication. please verify the correct package name and sha-1 are configured in the firebase console.

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188121/sha-1-problem-with-firebase-and-google-auth-and-phone-auth

Comment: thanks my issue is resolved

Comment: Can you please share your answer!

Comment: Can you tell me what you do to solve it?