# Xamarin forms google-services feature only works on debug and not on release

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms, google-play-services

I have an app developed with Xamarin forms that has Google Firebase Login. The app works well as I created the project, added the SHA-1 finger prints.

when I run the app on a physical device from Visual Studio debug it signs in fine but when I create a release and try running the .Apk file on another device the app installs but the Google login feature does not work.

how do I make the SHA1 for debug work for release also?

please suggest

Comment: I recommend that you use [App Center Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/) in your APP , we can review the log on the  app Center Portal .The App Center Diagnostics SDK collects information about crashes and errors in your apps and uploads them to the App Center portal for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because of the release apk has a different SHA-1 and SHA-256 value than the debug apk.

You may have a look at the [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188121/sha-1-problem-with-firebase-and-google-auth-and-phone-auth).

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Comment: Ok. But this did not solve the issue. I am guessing its a firebase SHA 1 issue

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know.